# Calculating Partitioned Matrices from subs

Tags: r, matrix, partitioning

Say you have a matrix A which is of size P × P and a number Q < P can be used to
take a partition of said matrix, where:

- A<sub>1</sub> is the upper-left sub matrix, with dimension Q × Q,
- A<sub>2</sub> is the upper-right sub matrix, with dimension Q × (P-Q),
- A<sub>3</sub> is the lower-left sub matrix, with dimension (P-Q) × Q,
- A<sub>4</sub> is the lower-rightsub matrix, with dimension (P-Q) × (P-Q).

Which looks like this:

```
      A1 | A2
A =   ---+----
      A3 | A4
```

How can you calculate the matrix:

[image: Matrix B]

Where 0<sub>q</sub> is a Q × Q matrix with zero elements.

I'm learning from a book called "Discovering Statistics using R" and although it discusses partitioned matrices, it doesn't show how to calculate one like the one given above and unfortunately I'm having no luck on the programming or maths based searches...

Any help, either mathematically and/or example R code would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unlike stats.stackexchange.som, SO does not support embedded LaTeX (unfortunately), so I edited your question to approximate that. Hope I did not mess up your intent.

Comment: @jlhoward Ah. Sorry about that. I didn't realise. Thanks for editing it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R` has various ways to grab blocks from matrices.  For instance, you can use a vector of indexes to reference a set of rows or set of columns using the extract function `[`, as shown in this example.  (The option `drop=FALSE` is needed if you must handle the case p=1 or q=1 so that `R` continues to treat the results as matrices and not just vectors.)

```
#
# Create a symmetric p-d matrix of size p+q.
#
p <- 2; q <- 3 # Both must be 1 or greater
x <- matrix(rnorm((p+q)^2 * 2), ncol=p+q)
a <- cov(x)
#
# Compute b.
#
i <- 1:p; j <- 1:q + p                         # Indexes of the blocks
b <- a[i,i, drop=FALSE] - 
     a[i,j, drop=FALSE] %*% solve(a[j,j, drop=FALSE], a[j,i, drop=FALSE])
```

Matrix inversion is implemented by `solve` (which is numerically more stable and efficient than computing the inverse of `a[j,j]` and multiplying that by `a[j,i]`), the single remaining multiplication is carried out by `%*%`, and `-` subtracts one matrix from another component by component.  In this fashion the code closely parallels the mathematical expression in the question.